# How to apply a short FIR low-pass filter in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

I am trying to implement something similar to what is detailed in this comment (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/4940#issuecomment-109952602) (reposted here):

> Anyway, a spike-train coded as a sum of delta functions is an analog signal. So when you bin the signal into rate or count histograms you will introduce aliasing, and your binning noise is the aliasing. The theory is explained in the classical French and Holden (1971) paper, though it is uncommon to use their "exact" anti-alias filter for reasons of efficiency. The easiest solution is to convolve each delta-function spike with a short FIR low-pass filter before you sample the spike train. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00291117

I haven't figured out how to accomplish this. I looked into various NumPy and SciPy functions but they all assume you know what you're doing :)

Comment: You should spend some time learning so we don't see you later asking about code you found on the internet but you can't make it work.  That said, with a little elbow grease these might get you started - http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ApplyFIRFilter.html and http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/FIRFilter.html